# Put legend outside the figure, so it will not affect the basic figure size?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am plotting two figures, but one figure has a bigger legend than the other one. When I insert them into Latex, the figures do not align because of the legend. What can I do with that?

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
##Input data
time_numbers =[1,
 2,
 3,
 4,
 5,
 6,
 7,
 8,
 9,
 10,
 11,
 12,
 13,
 14,
 15,
 16,
 17,
 18,
 19,
 20,
 21,
 22,
 23,
 24]
time =['t1',
 't2',
 't3',
 't4',
 't5',
 't6',
 't7',
 't8',
 't9',
 't10',
 't11',
 't12',
 't13',
 't14',
 't15',
 't16',
 't17',
 't18',
 't19',
 't20',
 't21',
 't22',
 't23',
 't24']
q_chp = {'CHP1': [100.0,
  145.235446793,
  173.414905451,
  300.0,
  300.0,
  300.0,
  300.0,
  300.0,
  300.0,
  300.0,
  300.0,
  298.739340007,
  277.382276604,
  293.400074156,
  241.404029168,
  300.0,
  300.0,
  300.0,
  300.0,
  300.0,
  300.0,
  300.0,
  300.0,
  285.24286244],
 'CHP2': [0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  22.4694104561,
  161.290322581,
  200.0,
  143.492769744,
  158.679215666,
  164.341727304,
  127.03003337,
  54.2083796811,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  29.0075392411,
  52.1319985169,
  72.1209118544,
  111.605487579,
  126.585094549,
  163.959955506,
  174.045235447,
  65.7767890248,
  3.04041527623,
  0.0]}
p_DA_all = {'CHP1': [163.571041755,
  72.6177233964,
  86.7074527253,
  150.0,
  150.0,
  150.0,
  150.0,
  250.0,
  250.0,
  250.0,
  250.0,
  250.150078571,
  252.692586119,
  233.171596553,
  238.587401808,
  171.457381913,
  150.0,
  150.0,
  150.0,
  211.41477065,
  222.798309098,
  150.0,
  150.0,
  142.62143122],
 'CHP2': [0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  11.234705228,
  80.6451612903,
  100.0,
  71.7463848721,
  167.189480449,
  225.519827809,
  233.977795399,
  126.655756539,
  64.9453218491,
  22.9257797352,
  17.9570481017,
  14.5037696206,
  26.0659992584,
  36.0604559272,
  55.8027437894,
  63.2925472747,
  81.9799777531,
  87.0226177234,
  32.8883945124,
  1.52020763812,
  0.0],
 'G1': [0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0],
 'G2': [91.8901989456,
  183.780397891,
  167.012097134,
  91.8901989456,
  91.8901989456,
  91.8901989456,
  104.36960203,
  200.0,
  200.0,
  200.0,
  200.0,
  200.0,
  200.0,
  200.0,
  200.0,
  200.0,
  170.385398357,
  100.0,
  106.991430536,
  200.0,
  200.0,
  185.242636565,
  174.546785572,
  128.927977582],
 'W1': [99.895902157,
  98.9590215696,
  98.9590215696,
  99.553667255,
  27.4646397641,
  29.538372483,
  125.669727383,
  129.23909098,
  124.480172191,
  116.022204601,
  142.987100604,
  150.976028152,
  83.3102055748,
  83.6927839164,
  79.051685714,
  104.619475971,
  95.3398600016,
  119.197256211,
  136.858879332,
  11.9623944541,
  8.92907317834,
  97.047540351,
  98.93300679,
  99.8791626268],
 'W_SP': [-3.998934516857844e-11,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  1.4949350418000051,
  79.6100970839,
  81.5741186112,
  2.00003569261753e-10,
  0.0,
  2.00003569261753e-10,
  2.00003569261753e-10,
  -4.00007138523506e-10,
  -2.00003569261753e-10,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  3.999929276687908e-10,
  0.0,
  6.018261613600018,
  2.00003569261753e-10,
  2.000000165480742e-11,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  4.000355602329364e-11]}


##Plots
#Power dispatch
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (4, 3))
ax1.stackplot(time, p_DA_all.values(),
             labels=p_DA_all.keys(), alpha=0.8)
ax1.set_xlabel('Time Period')
ax1.set_ylabel('Power [MW]')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0,1.02,1,0.2), loc="lower left",
                mode="None", borderaxespad=0, ncol=3) 

plt.xticks(np.arange(min(time_numbers)+1, max(time_numbers)+1, 3.0))
plt.savefig('Power_int.pdf', dpi=100, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show    

#Heat dispatch Integrated
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (4, 3))
ax.stackplot(time, q_chp.values(),
             labels = q_chp.keys(), alpha=0.8)
ax.set_xlabel('Time Period')
ax.set_ylabel('Heat [MW]') 
#ax.legend(loc='upper left')   
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0,1.02,1,0.2), loc="lower left",
                mode="None", borderaxespad=0, ncol=3)
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(time_numbers)+1, max(time_numbers)+1, 3.0))
plt.savefig('Heat_int.pdf', dpi=100, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show
```

The result I get when I insert them into Latex:

[image]

As you can see, the figures do not align with each other. Can someone please help me?

Here is the code how I insert it in Latex (Overleaf) (from PDF)

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.99\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{Power_int.pdf}
\caption{Power dispatch}\label{fig:Power_int}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.99\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{Heat_int.pdf}
\caption{Heat dispatch}\label{fig:load}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Power and heat dispatch in the integrated market framework}
\label{fig:image2}
\end{figure}
```

And two Images:
[Power_int](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D8oqBNq-iuDrn0JPZGyrm-Y0VhRZrILn/view?usp=sharing)
[Heat_int](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17SLoYtmgS5BxUJhhgezMXTweOTVWmG36/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you share the two figure and show how you include them in your latex file? Maybe one could simply use adjustbox to fix the vertical alignment

Comment: Maybe you want to remove `bbox_inches='tight'`, as that cuts away whitespace which is different for both plots

Comment: Thank you for adding the relevant code to solve your problem. I votes to reopen, but in the mean time, you can simply bottom align your subfigures: https://pastebin.com/j2JnPmSH

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably could fix this in LaTeX -- in your image the (a) and (b) captions are misaligned too, and those look like they were latex-generated.

Or you could put both plots into one figure, which will also align things:

```
##Plots
#Power dispatch
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize = (8, 3))
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8, bottom=0.2) # increase space for a big top legend
axs[0].stackplot(time, p_DA_all.values(),
             labels=p_DA_all.keys(), alpha=0.8)
axs[0].set_xlabel('Time Period')
axs[0].set_ylabel('Power [MW]')
axs[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0,1.02,1,0.2), loc="lower left",
                mode="None", borderaxespad=0, ncol=3) 

axs[0].set_xticks(np.arange(min(time_numbers)+1, max(time_numbers)+1, 3.0))


#Heat dispatch Integrated

axs[1].stackplot(time, q_chp.values(),
             labels = q_chp.keys(), alpha=0.8)
axs[1].set_xlabel('Time Period')
axs[1].set_ylabel('Heat [MW]') 
#axs[1].legend(loc='upper left')   
axs[1].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0,1.02,1,0.2), loc="lower left",
                mode="None", borderaxespad=0, ncol=3)
axs[1].set_xticks(np.arange(min(time_numbers)+1, max(time_numbers)+1, 3.0))
plt.savefig('Power_and_Heat_int.pdf', dpi=100, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

You could also have a single top legend for the whole figure, since you share colors for CHP1, CHP2 in the two axes. One or two figures, or axes, or legends, all are possible and eventually it depends on what you think is most readable in context.

[image: Two-axis figure with separate top legends]